# How do I change the text "There are no articles in this category" in Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I am looking to customize the wording that displays when there are no articles in a category for a category blog. Right now, Joomla displays "There are no articles in this category. If subcategories display on this page, they may contain articles."

I know how to turn this message off, but I can't seem to find where I can edit the text, or override it. I've searched through all the Joomla files (Find phrase in Dreamweaver in all files) and nothing came up.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should utilize the Joomla Language Manager under Extension Manager in the Joomla Administrator.  Just select Language Override, click New, and search for your phrase.

Here is the Joomla docs for this:

https://docs.joomla.org/Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

This will ensure that when Joomla core is updated you don't loose the change.  Otherwise you would need to hack the Joomla core files which is a very bad idea.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize I could search for the wording in that option. I thought I could only search for the Language field name, which I didn't know. Thank you so much!